# Rsync in chrooted ssh in alpine docker image result in failed to set permissions

Tags: docker, ssh, rsync, alpine-linux, chroot

I use a simple dockerfile from alpine with openssh and rsync installed.
Ssh users are chrooted to their home directory and rsync and bash executable as well as chown, chmod etc. and their library are copied to the user directory so that rsync can be executed through ssh.

When I use rsync with -p options (included in -a) :

`rsync  -a -e 'ssh -p 2222' /home/user/Pictures/ localhost:/backups/071120`

I get an error :

> rsync: failed to set permissions on "/backups/071120/.Screenshot from
> 2019-12-26 13-47-24.png.NKoiaj": No such file or directory (2) The

files are copied but obviously the permissions are not set correctly.

I tried to change permission using ssh and everything works as expected so it should not a be a folder permission issue.
And then I tried to use a ubuntu base image and it works as expected, so there is something in the alpine base image that prevent rsync to change permission.

Any idea of what it could be ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue working with **rsync** on alpine-based image.
Solution should be to disable the `chroot` setting on the `rsyncd.conf` file by specifying **no** at the following line:

```
use chroot = no
```

As per documentation ( https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html ) setting the option to **yes** could complicate the preservation of users and groups by name

> use chroot
>
> If "use chroot" is true, the rsync daemon will chroot to
> the "path" before starting the file transfer with the client. This has
> the advantage of extra protection against possible implementation
> security holes, but it has the disadvantages of requiring super-user
> privileges, of not being able to follow symbolic links that are either
> absolute or outside of the new root path, and of complicating the
> preservation of users and groups by name (see below).

Comment: I'm not using the rsync daemon, I still tried with no luck...

Comment: Did you try disabling chroot? Do you confirm this doesn't solve on your scenario?

Comment: Yes I tried, bot in /etc/rsyncd.conf and in the user home. I even tried to use command="rsync --config=/etc/rsyncd.conf --server" to be sure it was used. But the file states that it's a "configuration file for rsync daemon" and I'm not using the daemon afaik.

Comment: I mixed up the command a bit sorry. This is what I did : I put a rsyncd.conf files modified as you suggested in the use home folder and then used this command on the client : `rsync --rsync-path="rsync --config=rsyncd.conf" -a -e 'ssh -p 2222'` etc. And I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of this problem, but I see it also in alpine. I ran with the same `rsyncd.conf`, but in a debian container, and it worked as expected.